# Car windows segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm doing a project in which we need to do segmentation of the window cars from inside the car.
I'm working with **OpenCV** but this is not mandatory. (Also python or C++ are OK)

Until now, I have some (not so good) results. I have followed this sequence:

1) Apply `cv2.grabCut()` in ROIs where windows might be.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Read Image
img = cv2.imread("test1.png",-1)

#Grab Cut iterations
itera = 30

p1 = True
if p1: # This takes quite long so this helps when debugging 
    gb_mask_w1 = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8) #output mask
    bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
    fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
    rect = (1,12,390,845) #ROI of window 1
    cv2.grabCut(img,gb_mask_w1,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,itera,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

    # 0-pixels and 2-pixels are put to 0 (ie background) and all 1-pixels and 
    # 3-pixels are put to 1(ie foreground pixels).
    mask_w1 = np.where((gb_mask_w1==3),0,1).astype('uint8') #

    gb_mask_w2 = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)#output mask
    rect_1 = (1500,12,323,820) #ROI of window 2
    cv2.grabCut(img,gb_mask_w2,rect_1,bgdModel,fgdModel,itera,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

    # 0-pixels and 2-pixels are put to 0 (ie background) and all 1-pixels and 
    # 3-pixels are put to 1(ie foreground pixels).
    mask_w2 = np.where((gb_mask_w2==3),0,1).astype('uint8')
```

2) Erode on the foreground pixels to have clean(er) edges

```
# Morphological Operations
kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)

eroded_w1  = cv2.erode(mask_w1,kernel,iterations = 1)
eroded_w2  = cv2.erode(mask_w2,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

3) Aplpy `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising()` to avoid artifacts

```
# DeNoise artifacts
mask_w1_porc = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(eroded_w1)
mask_w2_porc = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(eroded_w2)
```

4) Just apply resulting mask & plot

```
img_treated = img.copy()

# Green background
bskg = np.zeros(img.shape[:3],np.uint8)  
bskg[:] = (0, 177, 64)

#Apply mask
img_treated[mask_w1_porc==0] = bskg[mask_w1_porc==0]
img_treated[mask_w2_porc==0] = bskg[mask_w2_porc==0]

#Plot
f,ax=plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0,0].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB ))
ax[0,1].imshow(mask_w1_porc)
ax[1,0].imshow(mask_w2_porc)
ax[1,1].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img_treated,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB ))
```

**Problems**:

- It happens that only a segment of the window is actually detected.
- It may happen that parts of the car are detected as window
- Very slow (~20 seconds per window)

**Is something working?**

- At least an important section of the windows is always detected
- It's robust to occlusion

**What do I want?**

- I'm wondering what can I add to this pipeline to have a better window detection => a filter to make `cv2.grabCut()`'s work easier?
- Maybe there is there a faster way?
- I'm avoiding machine learning or AI aproaches because we work with a *not so powerful* computer. But I'm open to those ideas

I'm adding the plot so that you can see the results (Original image, both masks and ouput):
[image: Output from all that code]

**[Edit]:**

I'm also posting an image with occlusion(which doesn't seem so fail but is the reason to detect windows instead of having fixed masks)

[image: Image with occlusion]

Comment: If the camera is fixed, the coordinates of the windows wont change. So no need to detection just crop using coordinates. Or what is the main reason for detection?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thank you for your answer, if a person is in between the camera and the window => only the window segment should be changed

Comment: But in your images seems no problem, you should share an image which you are having difficulty to detect windows.

Comment: I'll upload an example like that

Comment: I just uploaded the occlusion image

Comment: Can you share the original images to reproduce your code? If you want, you can obscure the faces.

Comment: @Ivan I am sorry but in your new images also your program is still detecting windows succesfully. or I misunderstood your problem?